# How to save the remaining string from strtok_r()?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to figure out how to pull the remaning string that needs to be parsed (the third parameter of strtok_r()), but am lost as to how to do so.
The initial input comes from a char pointer defined by malloc().

The code below is what I am trying to achieve.

```
num = strtok_r(raw_in, delim, &rest_of_nums);

while(rest_of_nums != NULL){

    while(num != NULL){

    //Compare num with fist digit of rest_of_nums
    num = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &rest_of_nums);

    }
    //Iterate to compare num to second digit of rest_of_nums
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pull"?

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the first line.

Comment: @Shawn I mean to get the string stored at the memory location of rest_of_nums.

Comment: Um... you already have it. What do you think `rest_of_nums` is?

Comment: I want the entire string. When I try and get that information it points only to the start of that memory. I need the string to do another parse using strtok_r. the memory location isn't good enough.

If something is super obvious please point it out, I'm new to C.

Comment: `strtok_r` changes the original string. The identity of the first separating character is lost. It has been documented.

Comment: Perhaps it is just sufficient to assign the return value of following strtok invocation to *another* variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to mix up `strtok()` and `strtok_r()`. The syntax of `strtok()` is as follows:

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

and the syntax of `strtok_r()` is as follows:

```
char * strtok_r ( char * str, const char * delimiters, char **saveptr );
```

When we call `strtok()` for the first time, the function expects a C string as argument for str, whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer and uses the position right after the end of the last token as the new starting location for scanning. The point where the last token was found is kept internally by the function to be used on the next call.

However, in `strtok_r()`, the third argument `saveptr` is a pointer to a `char *` variable that is used internally by `strtok_r()` in order to maintain context between successive calls that parse the same string.

A sample example for `strtok_r()` is as follows:

```
    char str[] = "sample strtok_r example gcc stack overflow";
    char * token;
    char * raw_in = str;
    char * saveptr;
    //delimiter is blank space in this example
    token = strtok_r(raw_in, " ", &saveptr);
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        printf("%s\n", saveptr);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveptr);
    }
```

The output should be as follows:

```
sample
strtok_r example gcc stack overflow
strtok_r
example gcc stack overflow
example
gcc stack overflow
gcc
stack overflow
stack
overflow
overflow
```

Source:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/

Questions are welcome.

Comment: I think I understand the difference, I am wondering if it is possible to get and store the string that raw_in points to.

Comment: Yes, you can get and store the string that raw_in points to. In the example above inside the while loop, try printing the string that raw_in points to and see the output.

Comment: `num = strtok_r(raw_in, delim, &rest_of_nums);`
`char keep = *rest_of_nums;`
`printf("%s\n",rest_of_nums);`
`printf("%s\n",keep);`

I get no output when printing keep. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Thank you! I think I was able to get what I want by using a character pointer for `*keep = rest_of_nums;`

Comment: Try the following code from my example
```while ((token = strtok_r(raw_in, " ", &raw_in))) {    printf("%s\n", raw_in);    printf("%s\n", token);}```

Comment: I tried the code you gave. It printed L, and then nothing. There is no L in the input file.

Comment: I have a new issue. Once I iterate through the while loop the char pointer `keep` only shows the first char, and not the entire string.

Comment: The example you're linking to is utterly b0rken! Hence this answer is wrong too.

Comment: Printing L ! Could you post your entire code file content that you are compiling to get such output? I am getting the output as mentioned above in my example (sample followed by strtok_r and then example). I am sure you are missing some thing. By looking at your complete code, I will be able to know what exactly you are missing.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I didn't get your point. Could you please elaborate? The example that I have provided is perfectly working in my system.

Comment: @SauravKumarSahu yet it is incorrect. The `strtok_r` usage in the question is correct, and the page you've linked to is incorrect. The documentation of `strtok_r` does not specify the contents of the `save_ptr` thus it cannot be used like in your answer. Everything is more or less ok until "A sample example for strtok_r() is as follows:", and then you quote an incorrect example that works just by fluke.

Comment: @SauravKumarSahu I did. That's why I am saying. Notice how the example there is passing NULL as the first argument on the subsequent iterations, as one should!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Now I have edited the example as per your suggestion. Thanks for the suggestion. However, the previous example was also working fine.